# Does Karl die when he saves his wife from being gassed

Tags: valiant-hearts

i just watched jacksepticeyes new video and i am now curious to see if karl dies he just wnt into emiles farm and his wife has so called been gassed

He just took the mask on and now jacksepticeye is on the battlefield with emile and it really really got me thinking if Karl dies

Answer (score 1):

Karl does **not** die when he saves his wife.

He will be taken into a hospital instead. Keep watching the videos, or play the game yourself, and it should become clear.

Answer (score -3):

i just watched him too but karl does survive as the dog goes and class anna and she comes and rescues him and takes him to the hospital where he is treated. his family also survives. But at the ned emile is killed after bieng kept as a war prisioner